# Creating UI design for specific screens only

Tags: android, size, screen

How do I create a layout for 400*800 and 720 *1280 and then a third layout for any phone smaller than these....and to declare them in the manifest

Comment: you cant target specific screen sizes only

Comment: Do you mean: 

- You want a special layout to appear for 720x1280, a second special layout to appear for 480x800, and some default layout to appear for every other size.

or

- You want one layout optimized for 480x800, but available to anything smaller than 720x1280

Comment: Those are not screen sizes. They are screen resolutions. You cannot "design for specific" screen resolutions, because screen resolutions are meaningless. You design around screen physical size and density, not resolution.

Comment: Thanks...I've rephrased the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general information you need is available on this page: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AlternativeResources

It is a common requirement to have one layout for small phones, another for large phones, and a third for tablets. This is generally solved by using the `sw<N>dp` ("smallestWidth") qualifier. For you, this would mean a directory structure like this:

```
res/
    layout/my_activity.xml
    layout-sw400dp/my_activity.xml
    layout-sw720dp/my_activity.xml
```

However, this approach considers *only* the "smallestWidth," and ignores the height of the device. This is often perfectly acceptable, but it may not work for you.

Unfortunately, there is no qualifier for "largestHeight" or similar; there is only one for "height" (i.e. current height). Still, you could leverage these qualifiers as follows:

```
res/
    layout/my_activity.xml
    layout-w400dp-h800dp/my_activity.xml
    layout-w720dp-h1280dp/my_activity.xml
```

No changes should be required to your manifest (other than declaring your Activity in the first place).

Comment: Thanks...great answer

Answer (score 0):

do you want to watch a very important course to learn more about what you are questioning?
Here is a link: https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud862